# Typescript: Using custom interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface Member {
  name: string,
  isLoggedIn: boolean,
  loginTime: Date
}
```

I would like to declare a list of members using this interface. I tried this:

```
public members: Member[] = [
    {name: "John"},
    {name: "Cena"}
];
```

Unfortunetly, I get the following error:

```
Type '{ name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Member[]'
```

What's the right way to declare an array of objects with custom interface to make it work with good practise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to declare isLoggedIn and logInTime as optional:

```
export interface Member
{
    name: string;
    isLoggedIn?: boolean;
    loginTime?: Date;
}

let members: Member[] = [
    {name: "John"},
    {name: "Cena"}
];
```

Another way is to provide default values when creating object:

```
export interface Member
{
    name: string;
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    loginTime: Date;
}

let members: Member[] = [
    {name: "John", isLoggedIn: false, loginTime: null},
    {name: "Cena", isLoggedIn: false, loginTime: null}
];
```